# moment.js accepts two digit month "01" when the format is M

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is the behavior correct when in **strict mode**, for format `M/D/YYYY`, moment.js will accept `01.09.2017`? Shouldn't it accept just `1.9.2017`, if there is the only "one `M`" in the format? Same applies for `D` days.

**Edit:**

```
moment('1/09/2017', 'MM/D/YYYY', true).isValid() // false
moment('01/09/2017', 'M/D/YYYY', true).isValid() // true -> why?
```

Why is `M` benevolent for `01`, but `MM` is not for `1`? Is it a bug?

Comment: Do you mean [strict mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3):

It could work not in correct way. In your example it works fine, but in other situation it could make a wrong result. [Moment format doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
moment("01.09.2017", "M/D/YYYY").format("M/D/YYYY");
//"1/9/2017"
moment("02-25-1995", "MMM/D/YY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
//"01/02/2025"
```

If you need to specify multiple formats, you can do it by set second argument as array of string formats. [Moment multiple format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)

```
moment("29-06-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MM", "DD-MM-YYYY"]); // uses the last format
moment("05-06-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MM-YYYY"]);          // uses the first format
```

For strict mode: this parameter effect to regular expression which parsing data and for number it will work correctly.

```
//Non strict regular    
Hb = /\d\d?/
//Strict regular
Sb = /\d\d/

d = b._strict;
case"MM":
case"DD":
case"YY":
case"GG":
case"gg":
case"HH":
case"hh":
case"mm":
case"ss":
case"ww":
case"WW":
   return d ? Sb : Hb;
```

In case with one letter always use non strict regular

```
case"M":
case"D":
case"d":
case"H":
case"h":
case"m":
case"s":
case"w":
case"W":
case"e":
case"E":
    return Hb;
```

So strict mode will fails in case

```
moment("1/9/1990", "MM/MD/YYYY", true).format("M/D/YYYY")
"Invalid date"
```

All this was test on momentjs version 2.7.0
In new version of moment 2.17.1 strict parameters used in formats `['MMM', 'MMMM'], ['dd', 'ddd', 'dddd']`

Comment: @mimo I can't comment on your question. In same way this situation is a bug, but if see wider, to correct parse day and month we need non strtict regular to parse values bigger than 9 > in strict mode. You can make bug report to Momentjs team about this situation

Comment: Those are regular expressions from momentjs repository? I wonder, why not to use 2 different regexes to be compliant with strict mode completely. Like /\d/ for month/days under 10 and for other numbers /\d\d/ (as you have written). I have opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3830

Comment: @mimo It's from unminified version of library, using in my current project. In their new version of momentjs they totally rewritten regular expression parse logic. But they still ignore strict mode for one letter format of days and month. I think it because that strict check would cause decrease of perfomance and make code more complexive and less flexible.